# How to get IAP App Store id?

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase

We used to provide paid-services via our website.Recently, we developed an ios app using APPLE's IAP to make the charge.
However, APPLE said we must make our product purchasable without user's registration, APPLE will help me to store the purchase record.

Then comes the big problem: we do not know who have bought the services, so we can not provide the services through our website.

If there is a way to bind the app store account to our website's own account, the problem could be solved, anyone can help me out of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no allowed way to get the Apple ID.  But after the IAP purchase and validation, you can enable the app to send a hashed token to a web site account chosen by the user in the app.  Then use that token to enable web site account features.

Comment: Thank you very much, seemed a practicable solution

Comment: but how can I recognize the user when the user logs in using another device

Comment: Validating the IAP receipt on a new device with your server should give you enough information to figure out on which old device it was previously used for logging into your web site.